# Python mysql.connector installation package

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

I got a script from the internet to connect to a database, but there wasn't documentation of the packages. I searched all mysql packages but couldn't find the correct one. This is what the code imports:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
```

and in some parts of the code they use this:

```
mysql.connector.connect(
```

does anyone knows the correct package? Im working in Ubuntu16.04 LTS btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package is: `mysql-connector-python`

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python
Be careful with the last version, I don't know if is fixed but there were some problems, try it and if doesn't work install the version 2.0.4

Is the official connector for MySQL, you can find some examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)